# How do I output webpack as a string using Node

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am trying to use Webpack to bundle a bunch of files. I have the following in my node code...

```
  webpack({
    entry: "./src/test",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
  }, function(err, stats){
    console.log("I would like to output the created js here");
  })
```

This works fine creating a file called bundle.js but I can't figure out how to output as a string instead.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you can do is to read the file, and then work with it as you want. 
e.g.

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
const config = require('../webpack.config');

const compiler = webpack(config);

compiler.run((err, stats) => {  
    const data = stats.toJson();

    const app = data.assetsByChunkName.app[0] //here you can get the file name  
    // if you don't have chunks then you should use data.assets;

    const file = fs.readFileSync('path to your output ' + app); //read the file
    //now you can work with the file as you want.
});

//Basic webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    app: 'Some path' // you can have different entries.
    entrie2 : ''
    .... more entries
  },
  output: {
    path: 'Some path'
  }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a solution that didn't require me to output it to disk but for now this works. Thanks!